# apxs Not Generating .so file?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to install Apache mod_xsendfile on a CentOS machine.

However, when I run:

```
apxs -c mod_xsendfile.c
```

no .so file is output. Instead it generates mod_xsendfile.la, mod_xsendfile.o, mod_xsendfile.slo, and mod_xsendfile.lo.

I can't understand why no .so file is generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's in .libs, check:

```
ls -l .libs/*.so
```